# Formatting and combining word frequency with other data machine learning python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm new in machine learning algorithms. I extensively read the scikit learn website and other SO post, which led me to build my first machine learning algorithm using the RandomForestClassifier and LinearSVC.

I'm working on medical notes. Each stay of a patient is associated (or not) to a code corresponding to a complication (bleeding, infection, heart attack...)

Using the notes, fitted and transformed with Countvectorizer and tfidfTransformer, i can accurately predict most of the codes. However, i'd like to add more data to my training dataset: length of stay, number of operations, title of operations, ICU stay duration...etc...

After parsing the web and SO, i ended up by adding all continuous/binary/scaled value to my word frequency array.

e.g: `[0,0,0.34,0,0.45,0, 2, 45]` (last 2 numbers are added data, whereas previous one match countvectorizer and tfdif.fit_transform(train_set)

However, this seems to me to be a gross way to combine data, and a huge number of words could mask others data.

I tried to set my data like: `[[0,0,0.34,0,0.45,0],[2],[45]]` but it doesn't work.

I searched the web, but no real clue, even though i might not be the first one facing this issue...:p

Thanks for your help

Edit:

Thanks for your detailed valuable answer. I really appreciated. However, what is exactly the range 0-1: is it the {predict_proba} value (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict) ?. I understood that the score is the accuracy of the prediction model. Then when you have all your predictions depending of each variable, do you average all of them ? Eventually, i'm working with multiple outputs, i guess it's not a problem since i can get a prediction for each of the output (btw predict_proba(X)  give me an array like [array([[0.,1.]]), array ([[0.2,0.8]]).....] with a random forest tree classifier. i guess one of the number is the probability of the output, but i haven't explored this yet !)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first solution of just appending to the list is the correct solution. However, you should think about what this is implying. If you have 100 words and add two additional features, each specific word will get the same "weight" as the added features - IE - your added features won't be treated very strongly in the model. Additionally, you're saying that the last feature with a value of 45 is 100x the value of the feature 4th from end (0.45).

One common way to get around that is to use an ensemble model. Instead of adding those features to your list of words and predicting, first build a prediction model just using the words. That prediction will be in the range 0-1 and will capture the "sentiment" of the article. Then, scale your other variables (minmax scaler, normal distribution, etc.). Finally, combine the score from the words with the last two scaled variables and run another prediction on a list like this [.86,.2,.65]. In this way, you have transformed all of the words to a sentiment score, which you can use as a feature.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT PER YOUR UPDATE ABOVE**

Yes, in this instance you could use the predict_proba, but really if everything is scaled correctly, and you are using 1/0 as your targets for a class you don't need the predict_proba. The idea is to take the prediction from the words and combine it with the other variables. You do not average the predictions, you make a prediction from the predictions! This is called ensemble learning. Train another model with the output of your predictions as the features. Here is a flow of what you need to do.[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed valuable answer. I really appreciated. I edited the first post for questions about predictions array.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i added another answer (below). I don't really understand how do you calculate the "sentiment" !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time and your detailed answer. I think i get it. In short:

1. Prediction based on words, and for each bag of words of the training set (t1), you pull out a "sentiment"
2. Create a new array for each training set row with the sentiment and others values->new training set(t2)
3. Make a prediction based on t2.
4. Apply previous steps to the test.

One more question though !

What is the "sentiment" value ?! For each bag of words, i have a sparse matrix (countvectorizer+tf_idf). So how do you calculate the sentiment ? Do you run each row of the test again the rest of the test ? and your sentiment is the clf.predict(X) value ?

Comment: Sentiment is just shorthand for whatever you are predicting. If you are predicting heart failure, it is the confidence your model has that a given bag of words case predicts heart failure. You predict the sentiment by feeding in your matrix as the cases, and a separate list of equal length of 0 or 1 if there is heart failure in that case or not to "Classifier 1". This may be any type of classifier, but you had mentioned random forest and linearsvc.

Comment: Ok, i get what you mean. What i can't figure out is: i have a training dataset with words, and an event (1/0). Right. I train my dataset to make a prediction for a new bag of words, and i get a predicted probabilty of the event depending of the bag of words. Right. But in your schema, i understand that you have a prediction for each row of the training dataset. So you imply that for each row of you're training dataset, you're running your prediction model to get the sentiment (ie the prediction) of each bag of words. What you defined earlier as 'you make a prediction from the predictions'.